# Angular failed to install on local system - npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT

Tags: node.js, angular

I have successfully installed Node and AngularCLI on my local system. And everything was okay. I have:

```
Angular CLI: 13.1.1
Node: 16.13.1
Package Manager: npm 8.1.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1301.1 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         13.1.1 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   13.1.1 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          13.1.1 (cli-only)
```

However, when I try to install Angular project with ng new myproject, I got this error:

```
- Installing packages (npm)...npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\BAMI\\Desktop\\MyApp\\APP-UI\\node_modules',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\BAMI\Desktop\MyApp\APP-UI\node_modules\sass\sass.dart.js'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'unlink',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\BAMI\\Desktop\\MyApp\\APP-UI\\node_modules\\sass\\sass.dart.js'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\BAMI\\Desktop\\MyApp\\APP-UI\\node_modules\\less',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\BAMI\Desktop\MyApp\APP-UI\node_modules\less\lib\less\environment\abstract-plugin-loader.js'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'unlink',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\BAMI\\Desktop\\MyApp\\APP-UI\\node_modules\\less\\lib\\less\\environment\\abstract-plugin-loader.js'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

I am doing the installation on my local system, without any security.

I did:

> npm  cache clear --force

The problem is still there.

How do I get this sorted out?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use this command to update globaly your npm

```
npm install -g npm
```

Comment: the problem is still there

Comment: try yarn install instead

Answer (score 1):

Check these steps:

- test your connection, seems there's a problem too
- nuke your node_modules folder
- reinstall your npm globally
- install again